# How to get username and password from Credential Manager?

Tags: java, spring-boot, credential-manager

In `application.properties` I want to store these data:

```yaml
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=my-email
spring.mail.password=my-email-password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Since my Git repository is public, I don't want anybody to see my email and password.

Since I am on Windows 11, Environment Variables are an option. But once I open this window, everybody sitting next to me can see my password since it is just plain text.

I want my password to be secure, even if it is stored on my own computer only.

So Instead of environment variables, I think it is a better approach to store the details in Credential Manager on Windows. I am using the dependency `spring-cloud-starter-vault-config`, version 4.0.0.

In Credential Manager I have added a generic credential and called it *Gmail*. And this is what I have tried in application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      uri: vault://wincred/Gmail
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: ${vault.generic.Gmail.username}
    password: ${vault.generic.Gmail.password}
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enabled: true
```

But I get these exceptions:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't retrieve default
> port from vault://wincred/Gmail
>
> Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: vault

Is what I am trying out even possible?

Comment: first sentance in the docs `Spring Cloud Vault Config provides client-side support for externalized configuration in a distributed system. With HashiCorp’s Vault` https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. Windows Credentials Manager has no connection to Hashicorp Vault.

Answer (score 1):

Credential Manager is really designed for managing credentials used  by internal  operating system features, such as the [Multiple Provider Router](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/multiple-provider-router).

Windows does provide a set of Cryptographic APIs, including the [Data Protection API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API), which is designed for the secure storage of arbitrary information using a cryptographic key derived from the user's logon password.